# preg_match not working. How to resolve?

Tags: php

PHP:

```
$Query = 'IMPORTED POUCH';
echo !preg_match('/[^\W_ ] /', $Query) ? 1 : 0;
```

I want to check Query is in English Language or in other Language. Why it outputting 0 instead of 1 How can I solve this issue?

Comment: can you put preg_match inside the if condition

Comment: @MehulJariwala Ternary operator working same as If-Else block.

Comment: what is your expected output? Edit your question with examples

Comment: Well... you can just check presence of English alphabet characters, but... not so sure about checking 'is English language or other language' - that would be pretty hard stuff...

Comment: And if you want to check only letters/space, try this: echo preg_match("/[^A-Za-z ]/", $q); If there is some character in your string, which is not letter, or space, this will return true(1).